# Does SonarQube support layered coverage reporting?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, continuous-delivery

Sonar supports the ability to separately report on unit vs integration tests, which is great:
http://www.sonarqube.org/measure-coverage-by-integration-tests-with-sonar-updated/

That said, we'd actually like to look at coverage from a number of different angles in order to make various investment decisions.

For instance, we currently have a number of testing technologies in place, many of which have been deemed "legacy".  It would be great to be able to look at a treemap of my product (perhaps sized by complexity or "rate of code churn") and see an overlay of which testing technologies are covering what areas:

- Selenium
- Telerik
- RSPEC
- Eggplant
- Etc

We're also building out a staged Continuous Delivery pipeline with multiple layers of testing.  For example:

- Post-Commit (Ensure your commit doesn't blow up the rest of the development team, very fast)
- Confidence (A deeper set of tests to cover all of the major test cases, slightly slower than Post-Commit, but still fairly fast)
- Full Regression (All the tests in our arsenal - very slow, but deep)

Similar to the case of testing technologies, it would be great to be able to overlay these layers onto a treemap to show how each stage is covering the product to make tradeoff decisions.

Has anyone able to do this using existing SonarQube plugins and techniques or is this something beyond what Sonarqube supports?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way I can rephrase my question so that it may generate answers?  I'm surprised that others trying to implement a scaled Continuous Delivery pipeline haven't already come across and solved this problem.

Comment: That sounds like it would be great.

Comment: It's api-accessible, maybe you could clobber something together and open-source it ;)